# Is there a way to tell what bottle neck is in slow rsync transfer

Tags: rsync

I am transferring a directory from a USB hard drive to my NAS device (SMB share).

**USB Hard Drive performance:**

```
sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
Timing cached reads:   27884 MB in  1.99 seconds = 13987.00 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 122 MB in  3.03 seconds =  40.24 MB/sec
```

**&SB Hard Drive Performance II:**

```
$ bonnie++ -d ./
Writing a byte at a time...done
Writing intelligently...done
Rewriting...done
Reading a byte at a time...done
Reading intelligently...done
start 'em...done...done...done...done...done...
Create files in sequential order...done.
Stat files in sequential order...done.
Delete files in sequential order...done.
Create files in random order...done.
Stat files in random order...done.
Delete files in random order...done.
Version  1.97       ------Sequential Output------ --Sequential Input- --Random-
Concurrency   1     -Per Chr- --Block-- -Rewrite- -Per Chr- --Block-- --Seeks--
Machine        Size K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP  /sec %CP
HOSTNAME 15776M  1141  59 29840   1 10710   0   658  23 10836   0  35.7   1
Latency              7727us   27844us    1466ms     713ms    1659ms     874ms
Version  1.97       ------Sequential Create------ --------Random Create--------
HOSTNAME        -Create-- --Read--- -Delete-- -Create-- --Read--- -Delete--
              files  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP
                 16     2   0   828   0     2   0     4   0     3   0     3   0
Latency              1835ms     738ms    3080ms    2400ms    1867ms    1744ms
1.97,1.97,HOSTNAME,1,1531037873,15776M,,1141,59,29840,1,10710,0,658,23,10836,0,35.7,1,16,,,,,2,0,828,0,2,0,4,0,3,0,3,0,7727us,27844us,1466ms,713ms,1659ms,874ms,1835ms,738ms,3080ms,2400ms,1867ms,1744ms
```

**rsync command**:

```
rsync -Pav ~/source/directory ~/target/dirctory
```

When `rsync` is doing its thing, skipping files which don't need copying (usually the first 10 minutes), the RX/Tx speeds (via `glances`) are around 1.4 MBps.

The moment it starts transferring files, two problems arise

1. The transfer speeds are quite slow (~100-200 KBps). I assume this has to do with the overhead associated with small files (~15 KB)
2. Every 4 or 5 files, the transfers seems to halt for 5-10s and the transfer rate is displayed to be 0 KBps (See logs below)

Any suggestions as to how to either fix or diagnose this problem would be appreciated.

**Logs:**

```
image-8.jpg
          11,754 100%  166.36kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#46, ir-chk=31730/238104)
 image-9.jpg
          10,975 100%  146.82kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#47, ir-chk=31729/238104)
 image-9.jpg
          11,755 100%  149.08kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#48, ir-chk=31728/238104)
 image-10.jpg
          11,125 100%  129.34kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#49, ir-chk=31727/238104)
 image-10.jpg
          12,150 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#50, ir-chk=31726/238104)
 image-11.jpg
          10,963 100%  162.21kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#51, ir-chk=31725/238104)
 image-11.jpg
          11,917 100%  161.63kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#52, ir-chk=31724/238104)
 image-4.jpg
          11,046 100%  147.77kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#53, ir-chk=31723/238104)
 image-4.jpg
          11,714 100%  136.18kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#54, ir-chk=31722/238104)
 image-5.jpg
          11,065 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#55, ir-chk=31721/238104)
 image-5.jpg
          12,151 100%  171.97kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#56, ir-chk=31720/238104)
 image-6.jpg
          10,777 100%  144.17kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#57, ir-chk=31719/238104)
 image-6.jpg
          11,922 100%  157.33kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#58, ir-chk=31718/238104)
 image-1.jpg
          10,870 100%  115.38kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#59, ir-chk=31717/238104)
 image-1.jpg
          15,583 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#60, ir-chk=31716/238104)
 image-1.jpg
          15,287 100%  995.25kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#61, ir-chk=31715/238104)
 image-3.jpg
          14,410 100%  502.58kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#62, ir-chk=31714/238104)
 image-4.jpg
          14,889 100%  354.64kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#63, ir-chk=31713/238104)
 image-5.jpg
          15,214 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#64, ir-chk=31712/238104)
 image-2.jpg
          14,493 100%  707.67kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#65, ir-chk=31711/238104)
```

Comment: Try running `rsync` as a daemon, without `ssh`

Comment: @shodanshok How does one do that?

Comment: you can [read this guide](https://www.jveweb.net/en/archives/2011/01/running-rsync-as-a-daemon.html) or, even better, [rsync man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: Actually, it sounds like you're running `rsync` purely locally, and using SMB for the network leg of the transfer. In this case, SMB is my first guess at the bottleneck. I'd try running `rsync` over ssh (if the NAS box supports it), an `rsync` daemon on the NAS box (as @shodanshok suggested, again if the box supports it), and using an NFS mount instead of SMB (once again, if the NAS box supports it). My guess is that any of those those would be faster than over SMB, but you have to test them to find out.